# Find a specific word in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I want to check a string really does contain a specific word. Like this,

#### Problem

- `"word"` string contains, `"word"` word, as same as;
- `"daword"` string contains, `"word"` word, as same as;
- `"dawordo"` string contains, `"word"` word.

#### What I want?

- `"word"` string should really contain, `"word"` word, as same as;
- `"(whitespaces)word(whitespaces)"` string should really contain, `"word"` word, as same as;
- `"da word"` string should really contain, `"word"` word as same as;
- `"da word o"` string should really contain, `"word"` word as same as;
- `"(white spaces)word"` string should really contain, `"word"` word as same as;
- `"word(white spaces)"` string should really contain, `"word"` word as same as;

---

How can I do this in JavaScript? Thanks!

Comment: So.. [`\bword\b`](https://regex101.com/r/prFE0E/2)?

Comment: Im so confused. I did not understand anything.

Comment: @George You god damn right! I did not know `\b` special character in Regular Expression, thanks for this important information. Thanks, it worked!

Comment: @MuhammedÇağlarTUFAN You're very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `\bword\b` will do the trick.

```js
// should use \b with regex
var str = 'testwordtest';
if(str.match(/\bword\b/)){
    console.log('match');
} else {
    console.log('no match');
}
```

Comment: @MuhammedÇağlarTUFAN nevermind, I misinterpreted the edit.

Answer (score 0):

## Use [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
const target = 'word';
const arr = ['word', ' word ', 'hello_word', 'not_here'];

arr.forEach(w => console.log(w, w.includes(target)));
```

Comment: Thansk for reply but, the problem is this :) I found the solution. With regex, `\bword\b` is fine!

Comment: I did explained the problem on the answer exactly, in string `'hello_word'`, `'word'` shouln't be matches, it should be matchful when like this `'hello word'`.

Comment: You did not. Assuming that `dawordo` return true, then why would `hello_word` not? Your question is not as detailed as it should be

Comment: In my question, why would `dawordo` or `hello_word` should return `true` as you understand?

Comment: __You literally asked for that__ `"dawordo" string contains, "word" word`

Comment: Am I *asking* the question or *describing* the *problem* in there?

Comment: How would I know? It's not like you wrote it in plain and correct English

Comment: Yes, you can't know, you are right. I have medium English too. But, at least I tried my best with creating headings and filling contents under these headings. Thanks for your help, have a good day, sir.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the indexof function. This will return -1 if the sentence does not contain the word you are looking for, otherwise it will return the offset.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

I suggest modifying the example a bit to first convert the string to lower if you are not looking for case sensitive.

```js
var str = "Hello world, Welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.toLowerCase().indexOf("welcome");
if(n > -1)
{
    console.log("The search string was located at offset " + n);
}
else
{
    console.log("The string did not contain the search string...");
}
```

Comment: Thansk for reply but, the problem is this :) I found the solution. With regex, `\bword\b` is fine!

Comment: @PaulIshak because, as OP says, this does not solve the problem